# Is it possible to run containers with port forwarding using ctr command?

Tags: containers, containerd

I'm currently using containerd to run my application container for testing, but having a problem with networking.

I need to send some requests to port 5000 of my application container though there's no description on ctr manual about running a container with port forwarding.

Using docker, we can do like as follows:

```
docker run test-image -d -p 5000:5000
```

Can I do the same thing using ctr command?
I know nerdctl can do this but it's hard to use this tool for some reasons within my company.

Answer (score 3):

ctr cannot, but you can download nerdctl and that will do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

No, `ctr` is not a comprehensive tool and it does not support all the commands that docker cli used to support.

There is no command in `ctr` for port forwarding.